# Jenkins git plugin fetching changes from GitHub timeout

Tags: git, jenkins

I know this question has been asked many times. My case is like this: I have a DEV and PROD Windows server, and they have the same version of git 1.9.5 installed to the same location.

1. It works on DEV, but not PROD.
2. It works with github.com, but not my company's github instance, github.opp.com.
3. The difference of git related plugin is attached, not sure if it's the issue. Upper one is DEV.

[image]

[image]

```
Building remotely on public_jendevslave_1 in workspace D:\public_jendevslave_1\workspace\DevOps\Test-GitHub
 > D:\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > D:\Git\bin\git.exe config remote.origin.url http://github.opp.com/DevOps/Sample.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from http://github.opp.com/DevOps/Sample.git
 > D:\Git\bin\git.exe --version # timeout=10
using .gitcredentials to set credentials
 > D:\Git\bin\git.exe config --local credential.username svc_appbuilder_dev # timeout=10
 > D:\Git\bin\git.exe config --local credential.helper store --file=\"C:\Users\SVC_SE~2\AppData\Local\Temp\git9162421949136116258.credentials\" # timeout=10
 > D:\Git\bin\git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress http://github.opp.com/DevOps/Sample.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually switch to git ssh to fix this issue.

Comment: Can you please explain more to resolve this issue at my end?